# <Glyphs FontUri absolute path error

Tags: silverlight, xaml, fonts

I have next problem:

it works(xaml):
Glyphs FontUri="Res;component/48230029-18BE-6784-E14A-6C3DD62CAE72.odttf" ...

but it not:
Glyphs FontUri="http://sorochak.com/powerlight_pro_test/fonts/48230029-18BE-6784-E14A-6C3DD62CAE72.odttf"...

how I can use external font or external dll with fonts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally, then you will need a clientaccesspolicy.xml in the root of http://sorochak.com that allows remote http access from Silverlight (I do not see that file on the site at the moment).

Use Fiddler to see what requests Silverlight is making to the site.